# Export hyper-v VM with differencing disk

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, export

I've created a test domain using Hyper-V with differencing disk, which works fine, you save a lot of space.

Now I want to export this environment using the Hyper-V manager, and import it to another machine.

But during the export of all machines who use differencing disk, the process fails with the message 'export failed'. Nothing more.

Questions;

-Is exporting VM with differencing disk supported by Hyper-V?

-Is maybe possible to just copy the files and manually reconstruct the situation?

-Can I merge the harddisks, so they all have private harddisks again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Starting in Windows Server 2012, you no longer need to export a virtual machine in order to be able to import it. But, the export functionality still exists and it can be an easy way to prepare virtual machines to be imported.*

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831535(v=ws.11).aspx

How about just copy all the files and import them on the target host?

Comment: That link doesn't tell anything about differencing disk. But coping them, and recreate the VM's manually does seem to work. Just make sure you also have the parent disk in place!